# Why are BIOS updates discouraged if they provide security improvements?

Tags: bios, updates

Frequently, I've noticed that motherboard manufacturers recommend against installing/upgrading BIOS updates unless there's some kind of issue you are encountering. The warning usually comes in the form as the following ([taken from a Supermicro BIOS download](https://www.supermicro.com/en/support/resources/downloadcenter/firmware/SYS-510T-ML/BIOS)):

> WARNING!
>
> Please do not download / upgrade the BIOS/Firmware UNLESS your system has a BIOS/Firmware-related issue. Flashing the wrong BIOS/Firmware can cause irreparable damage to the system.
>
> In no event shall Supermicro be liable for direct, indirect, special, incidental,or consequential damages arising from a BIOS/Firmware update.

Why would a manufacturer recommend against its own BIOS update if it provides enhancements and security improvements? For instance, [this BIOS upgrade](https://www.supermicro.com/Bios/softfiles/15152/X11SSM-F_BIOS_2.7_release_notes.pdf) resolved several Intel CVE issues and only includes security updates. Looking at just a few of the CVEs would seem to me that it's actually rather important to make sure the BIOS is updated despite a user not having any "BIOS/Firmware-related issues".

Is this recommendation against BIOS updates just to reduce liability for the manufacturer and support/warranty claims in case a bad BIOS update causes the device to stop functioning? How should a user decide whether to install a BIOS update in light of the manufacturer's recommendation?

Comment: Because there is a risk that it may brick the pc if the bios update fails for any reason., do it at your own risk is what they are saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bios update process can be either complicated or dangerous.

If a vendor does not implement integrity and signature checks in their bios update process, it is possible to install a wrong bios (e.g., for a different product) or a bios containing viruses, back doors, or other issues.  Installing a wrong bios could irreversibly brick a machine, with the only remedy to unsolder the bios chip and replace it with a valid one.  Installing a half downloaded image or half installing a whole image could cause similar problems, which is why the bios update procedure frequently includes severe warnings about not turning the machine off during the bios update.

Having said that, some vendors *do* implement integrity and signature checks in their bios upgrade process and the system will not accept an invalid bios image.  Many vendors, even desktop machines, have duplicate bios images specifically so that you can upgrade one and fall back to the other if the upgrade fails for any reason.

So the warning you are seeing is an indicator that the vendor does not implement basic checks or have a redundant bios in the machine as a fallback, or maybe the vendor doesn't do a lot of testing of their released updates.  Vendors like this are inappropriate if you need to put a machine in a high security environment.

Comment: *"So the warning you are seeing is an indicator that the vendor does not implement basic checks or have a redundant bios in the machine as a fallback."* - I don't think so. Today's firmware usually covers a range of different systems and not just a single mainboard. So in my opinion it is more likely that the a) the firmware is not relevant for the specific system and b) maybe not that well tested on the specific system due to covering such a lot of systems and configurations, and thus more likely to break things.

Comment: The warning is on the website and it comes up in the upgrader tool even when you do have the correct firmware, so (a) is irrelevant and  (b) it _is_ for the specific system.  You've missed the point.

Comment: With "specific system" I mean the combination of mainboard, specific components (CPU, memory, graphic card, network cards ...), OS ... .  Firmware might fix compatibility or stability issues which fix issues with other systems using the same mainboard but not with this specific configuration. But firmware might add new problems to this specific configuration, so better don't touch a running system unless there is an actual need (like a security fix or fixed hardware problem) .

Comment: Dell releases firmwares frequently for nearly every component in their system and the kinds of compatibilities you mention rarely happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are BIOS updates discouraged if they provide security improvements?

I don't see such claim in what you cite. What you cite is instead about installing firmware only when actually needed. Such a need might be due to hardware issues with previous firmware but it might also be due to security issues or because some new features in the new firmware are wanted.

In fact, I see quite the contrary in case of fixed security issues. Like [this information from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000199279/dsa-2022-122?lwp=rt) which says

> ... See the table below for Dell Client BIOS releases containing resolutions to these vulnerabilities. **Dell Technologies recommends all customers update at the earliest opportunity.**

As for why to not install firmware updates if not needed: today's firmware needs to cover a range of systems which a wide range of configurations, sometimes specific to only few customers. Given how deep at the hardware level firmware changes the behavior of a system it might be that an update will break some specific configurations or make them unstable. Not everything could be tested before and some configurations might work only because some component is relying on a specific undocumented behavior of another one - and this undocumented behavior might be broken with an update.

Thus, what they recommend is basically to not touch a running system unless actually needed.

Comment: Dell is one of the companies that sign their firmware and check it before accepting it, and most of their systems have redundant firmware at least during the install process.

Answer (score -1):

The title of your question is wrong and shows you misinterpreted what you read.

The title of your question states "Why are BIOS updates discouraged if they provide security improvements?"

What you quoted, says "Please do not download / upgrade the BIOS/Firmware UNLESS your system has a BIOS/Firmware-related issue."

When it comes to security, if there's a security related upgrade, that'd be for what'd be considered a security related issue!